.NET 8 dependency injection best practices
I am upgrading to .NET 8 and wondering on the Dependency Injection best practices. Do people manually register all dependencies, for example
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, SmsNotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, EmailNotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, PushNotificationService>();

In our project we could have hundreds of these. Or are people using some other patterns for registering all the dependencies?

Are you registering different implementations of the same interface?

Not for 99% of the interfaces, but a small number.

"In our project we could have hundreds of these" - really ?

It's a million lines of code project, with hundreds of services.

I'm glad I won't be having to do any debugging in that! :)

Didn't you already ask this? What makes this question different from your last? Didn't this provide an answer?

Have you looked at Scrutor?

I am, personally, using extension methods created inside the project that defines those services.
public static IServiceCollection AddNotifications(this IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, SmsNotificationService>();
    services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, EmailNotificationService>();
    services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, PushNotificationService>();
}

So, you end up registering services in you project like you do it with built-in services e.g.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddNotifications();
builder.Services.AddDatabase("{Connection String}");
builder.Services.AddStorage("{Connection String}");

In case you have quite a lot of services and there is some registration pattern you may try to use reflection to scan for implementation of interface and based on that register types, but that comes with downside of not having the capability to find direct references of types and in most cases is not worth to do it to save you writing registrations by hand. Anyway, it is also an option.
